# Running npm looks for a binary in current directory

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

Whenever I call npm or other binaries such as rails, it invokes nodejs and says node cannot find a module.

For example, running npm in the homefolder would tell me:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/jekku/node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

Running npm in another folder would say

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/jekku/somefolder/node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

What is going on here?

Edit:

This also happens with rvm. Running rvm says:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/jekku/bash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

Comment: I have, by the way, tried uninstalling nodeJS. but to no avail it still fails.

Comment: goto node directory where u install node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is because I overwrote the 'env' binary in /usr/bin with a binary of nodeJS.

In order to restore the binary, I reinstalled the coreutils package for linux.

This causes all interpreters with preprocessor commands '#!/usr/bin/env' to use nodeJS instead of detecting the correct ENV to run the script with.